# Backbone.Controller documentation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I see some articles referring to **Backbone.Controller.extend** but can't find any documentation on http://backbonejs.org

Is it not documented or there is some newer version of backbone than 0.9.2? Or there is a plugin for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Controller was renamed [Router](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) in Backbone version 0.5.0

Quote from the 0.5.0 [changelog](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/scriptViewChangelog/Backbone-js-Changelog-66339.html)

> Controller was renamed to Router, for clarity.